# Click on item in ActionBar with tabs in Android 4

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am using an ActionBar with three Tabs. I also have a item in the ActionBar. I want to react on a click on these item different depending on the selected tab. How can I do this?

Code from my activity:

```
public class CreateProjectManually extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private static ArrayList<String> buildingList;
    private static ArrayList<String> roomList;
    private static ArrayList<String> deviceList;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
     * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
     * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_project_manually);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // set the app icon as an action to go home
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        //enable tabs in actionbar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
        // Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actionbar
     * */ 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            //TODO Speichern implementieren
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Speichern",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            break;
        case R.id.menu_add:
            //TODO Eintrag hinzufügen implementieren
            if(getItem()==0){

            }
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateProject.class);
            intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_CreateProjectManually_Activity");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;    
        default:
            break;
        }
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_create_project_manually, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment building_fragment = new BuildingFragment();
            Fragment room_fragment = new RoomFragment();
            Fragment device_fragment = new DeviceFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                args.putInt(BuildingFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
                building_fragment.setArguments(args);
                return building_fragment;
            case 1:
                args.putInt(RoomFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
                room_fragment.setArguments(args);
                return room_fragment;
            case 2:
                args.putInt(DeviceFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
                device_fragment.setArguments(args);
                return device_fragment;
            default: return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.building).toUpperCase();
                case 1: return getString(R.string.room).toUpperCase();
                case 2: return getString(R.string.devices).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment representing building structure
     */
    public static class BuildingFragment extends Fragment {
        public BuildingFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviews, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewfragment);

            buildingList = new ArrayList<String>();

            ListAdapter listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, buildingList);

            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(listenAdapter); 

            return view;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment representing room structure
     */
    public static class RoomFragment extends Fragment {
        public RoomFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviews, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewfragment);

            roomList = new ArrayList<String>();

            ListAdapter listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, roomList);

            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(listenAdapter); 

            return view;
        }
    }


    /**
     * A fragment representing device structure
     */
    public static class DeviceFragment extends Fragment {
        public DeviceFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviews, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewfragment);

            deviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

            ListAdapter listenAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);

            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(listenAdapter); 

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you had the answer all along:

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

Comment: But I have to use the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to react on a click on a item in the ActionBar. How can I combine this method with the `onTabSelected()`method? But I have to use the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to react on a click on a item in the ActionBar. How can I combine this method with the `onTabSelected()`method? Or should I inflate three different menu item in the `onTabSelected()`method?

Comment: When you create a tab, before you add it to the actionbar, you can set the tablistener -> tab.setTabListener(this);